# issues with aws_vpc_dhcp_options usage

Tags: terraform

I am creating a two VPC deployment. Both VPCs are being deployed via modules. In module VPC01 I am defining the dhcp options using:

```
resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options" "dhcp_domain_name" {
  domain_name          = var.domain_name

  tags = {
    Name = var.domain_name
    Creator = var.creator_name
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "dns_resolver" {
  vpc_id          = aws_vpc.infra-vpc.id
  dhcp_options_id = aws_vpc_dhcp_options.dhcp_domain_name.id
}
```

So this will define the vpc dhcp options when this vpc is deployed. Now when I want to deploy my send vpc how do I associate this vpc with the same vpc dhcp option set created?

I was trying to use:

```
resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "dns_resolver" {
  vpc_id          = aws_vpc.infra-vpc.id
  dhcp_options_id = aws_vpc_dhcp_options.dhcp_domain_name.id
}
```

When I do this I get this error:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on modules/vpc-intapp/infra-vpc.tf line 173, in resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "dns_resolver":
 173:   dhcp_options_id = aws_vpc_dhcp_options.dhcp_domain_name.id

A managed resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options" "dhcp_domain_name" has not been
declared in module.vpc-intapp.
```

I need to somehow get the value of the vpc dhcp option into my second module. So how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules can't directly reference resources created in other modules. If you want a resource to be shared/referenced by multiple modules, you either need to create it outside the modules, and pass it as an input variable to both modules, or you need to define it as an output from one module, and pass it as an input to the other module.

Since you've already created the first set of resources, I would go with the second option. Add this to the first VPC module:

```
output "vpc_dhcp_options_id" {
  value = aws_vpc_dhcp_options.dhcp_domain_name.id
}
```

Add this to the second VPC module:

```
variable "vpc_dhcp_options_id" {}
```

And change the second VPC module to use the module's input variable:

```
resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "dns_resolver" {
  vpc_id          = aws_vpc.infra-vpc.id
  dhcp_options_id = var.vpc_dhcp_options_id
}
```

Finally, pass the output value from the first module as an input value to the second module:

```
module "my_first_vpc" {
  source = "..."
}

module "my_second_vpc" {
  source = "..."
  vpc_dhcp_options_id = module.my_first_vpc.vpc_dhcp_options_id
}
```

Comment: Same state file. I just want every VPC created after the initial module creates the DHCP option to use that one and not create another. Is there a different method if same statefile?

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Now I get this error:


Error: InvalidDhcpOptionsID.NotFound: The dhcpOptions ID 'var.vpc_dhcp_options_id' does not exist
        status code: 400, request id: 6e0ed0bd-fcc3-4935-81ca-43d11dc2a7c1

  on modules/vpc-intapp/infra-vpc.tf line 169, in resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "dns_resolver":
 169: resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "dns_resolver" {

Comment: You've surrounded the variable reference in quotes somewhere. You haven't provided your code so I can't point out where.

Comment: Ok You are correct on that one, and the reason I did that is because before this last error the one I received before the quotes was this:

Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on modules/vpc-intapp/infra-vpc.tf line 171, in resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "dns_resolver":
 171:   dhcp_options_id = var.vpc_dhcp_options_id
    |----------------
    | var.vpc_dhcp_options_id is object with 9 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "dhcp_options_id": string required.

Comment: That sounds like your output value is the entire object instead of the ID. Did you do this: `value = aws_vpc_dhcp_options.dhcp_domain_name` instead of this: `value = aws_vpc_dhcp_options.dhcp_domain_name.id`?

Comment: Ok I got it to work. For some reason rather then using the _id in the resource for second module I had to use .id.

'resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "dns_resolver" {
  vpc_id          = aws_vpc.infra-vpc.id
  dhcp_options_id = var.vpc_dhcp_options.id
}'

Comment: That's because you did an output of the entire object, instead of the resource ID as I mentioned in my last comment. Anyway, glad you got it to work.

Comment: What is the different between doing an output of the whole object vs resource ID?

Comment: Output of the entire object makes all object properties available. Output of the Id makes only the ID available. This is basic Terraform syntax stuff.

Comment: I have been "tinkering" with TF for a bit, but just did my first VPC deploy for work, so I am still learning some things. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.